# Parsing and Ignore Null Data Inside Multidimensional Array on Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array, that shown from console.log(temp) in my dashboard.component.ts just like this:

```
[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"user_id":"ismail.rahman.saanin@gmal.com","status":"Idle"},{"user_id":"lutfi.aldi.nugroho@gmil.com","status":"Overload"}]]
```

Basically, this kind of array (contain null array inside) is rare condition. But it disturb me, i cant parse the data.

My Dashboard.component.ts

```
this.scheduleService.getShiftSchedule().subscribe((temp)=>{
  this.api = temp;
//console.log(temp);
  var ids = [['user_id', 1], ['status', 2]],
  result = Object.keys(temp).map(o => ids.map(([key, id]) => ({ id, content: temp[o][key] })));
  this.tablePresetData = result;
})
```

My question is, how to filter data if there is condition null array in multidimensional array like in my case ?

Need Help, Thanks guys...

Comment: you wanna remove empty arrays from the array?

Comment: Perhaps you should first filter the array like `temp.filter(arr => arr.length)` so that any empty array is filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `length` is greater than `0`.

```js
let arr = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"user_id":"ismail.rahman.saanin@gmal.com","status":"Idle"},{"user_id":"lutfi.aldi.nugroho@gmil.com","status":"Overload"}]];
arr = arr.filter(item => Array.isArray(item) && item.length > 0)
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: the given error "Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'." @Maheer Ali

Comment: @aldi you need to call it on `Array`. not `Object`

Comment: i change arr with temp that contain array. and i call it with console.log(temp). @Maheer Ali

Comment: @aldi you might be making some mistake because its working fine in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `.filter()` and return element `.length` where `0` evaluates to false

```
let [res] = array.filter(({length}) => length)
```

or use `.flat()`

```
let res = array.flat()
```

Comment: the given error "Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'." @guest271314

Comment: @aldi `[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"user_id":"ismail.rahman.saanin@gmal.com","status":"Idle"},{"user_id":"lutfi.aldi.nugroho@gmil.com","status":"Overload"}]]` is the input,  and `[{"user_id":"ismail.rahman.saanin@gmal.com","status":"Idle"},{"user_id":"lutfi.aldi.nugroho@gmil.com","status":"Overload"}]` is expected output, correct?

Comment: but it still error man "Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'."

Comment: and what does it means with res ?

Comment: @aldi The resulting array